# Marginalizing conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I have the joint distribution:
$p(d,i,g,s,l)=p(d)p(i)p(g|d,i)p(s|i)p(l|g)$

I'm looking for the conditional probability that:
$p(i|l,s)$

I found that i need to marginalize over d,g and i like so:
$p(i|l,s)=\frac{p(i,l,s)}{p(l,s)}=\frac{\sum_{d}\sum_{g}p(d,i,g,s,l)}{\sum_{d}\sum_{g}\sum_{i}p(d,i,g,s,l)}=\frac{\sum_{d}\sum_{g}p(d)p(i)p(g|d,i)p(s|i)p(l|g)}{\sum_{d}\sum_{g}\sum_{i}p(d)p(i)p(g|d,i)p(s|i)p(l|g)}$

Where i get stuck is here:
$p(i|l,s)=\frac{\sum_{g}p(s|i)p(l|g)}{\sum_{g}\sum_{i}p(s|i)p(l|g)}$

I'm unsure how to continue from here, or if i've made a mistake. If so, is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: not sure how you found the last one. And are you trying to get rid of all the summations, which is probably not possible?

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a Bayesian network problem. You're probably not going to get rid of the summations, but you can still calculate the conditional probability once you decompose the joint into its factors (your 2nd to last equation).

Comment: @tchainzz, not sure i understand. Could you elaborate?